# Why can not I display the data in a template for some models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm new in django and i'm trying to display data in templates. Some models it can be displayed well. But, not for some models, and i don't know how it can be hapen.

This is my models:

```
class DosenPublikasi(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField(db_column='UserID', max_length=50, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    publikasiid = models.IntegerField(db_column='PublikasiID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'dosen_publikasi'

class Publikasi(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    judul = models.CharField(db_column='Judul', max_length=255, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'publikasi'
```

And i try to display `DosenPublikasi` models. So this is my views:

```
def lihat_riwayat_publikasi(request):
    username_session = request.session['username']
    hak_akses_session = request.session['hak_akses']
    dosenpublikasi = DosenPublikasi.objects.select_related().all()
    data = {
            'object_list':dosenpublikasi,
            'username':username_session,
            'hak_akses':hak_akses_session,
    }
    return render(request, 'lihat_riwayat_publikasi.html', data)
```

And this is my html templates:

```
            {% for dosenpublikasi in object_list %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td> 
              <td>{{ dosenpublikasi.userid }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
```

My question:

1. why when i try to display `DosenPublikasi` models it can't be displayed, but when i try to display anoter models like `Publikasi` it displayed properly ?
2. How is the solution ?

Comment: We don't know what you're seeing, so we can't begin to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need one to do something like this

```
username_session = request.session['username']
hak_akses_session = request.session['hak_akses']
dosenpublikasi = DosenPublikasi.objects.all()
data = {
        'object_list':dosenpublikasi,
        'username':username_session,
        'hak_akses':hak_akses_session,
}
return render(request, 'lihat_riwayat_publikasi.html', data)
```

Then on your html you will haven something like this

```
{% for items in object_list %}
{{ items.abdul }}   
{% endfor %}
```

The other thing, you don have to have the id field on your models django will do the trick for you, happy coding @rang